# не могу настроить Bitrix Rss

Tags: php, битрикс, rss

Не могу настроить модуль на импорт rss в битриксе,
вот часть кода:

```
$arRes = CIBlockRSS::GetNewsEx("www.example.ru", 80, "/bitrix/rss.php", "ID=3&LANG=ru&TYPE=news&LIMIT=5");
```

Вопрос: будет ли работать на localhost'е, какой нужно указать порт если сайт "лежит" на localhost'е и где можно посмотреть ID нужного мне инфоблока

Answer (score 0):

localhost по умолчанию работает на 80 порте, что бы убедиться выполните команду netstat -a -o и посмотрите кто крутиться на 80 порту.
ID инфоблока виден в URL, GET параметре IBLOCK_ID если открыть нужный инфоблок.
На localhost'е должен работать так как вы делаете внешний запрос в интернет,а не наоборот.